# jquery animate and make div center

Tags: jquery

when the div is getting fadeout then i want to make it center. please review the code and tell me what to change to make it proper.

here is the implementation url http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/17/
here is the code.

```
var grower = $('.grower');
var flag=0;

$('.click').click(function(){
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    var left = windowWidth/2 - 150;
    var top = windowHeight/2 - 150;
    var w = 300;
    var h = 300;

    if(flag==0)
    {
        $('.grower').show()
        grower.css({left:windowWidth/2, top:windowHeight/2});
        grower.animate({width:w, height:h, left:left, top:top,opacity : 1},500);
        flag=1;
    }
    else if(flag==1)
    {
        grower.animate({width:h/2, height:w/2, left:(windowWidth/2 -
            $('#grower').width()), top:(windowHeight/2 -
            $('#grower').height())},function() {$('.grower').fadeOut("slow");flag=0;});
        flag=0;
    }
});
```

Comment: first of all - there is no element with id grower, so $('#grower').width() and $('#grower').height() always returns 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/34/

My solution using jQuery UI animations.

### HTML

```
<div class="click">Click here</div>
<div class="grower"></div>
```

### CSS

```
.click {background:#ccc; border:1px solid black; padding:10px; display:inline-block}
.grower {width:0; height:0; background:red; position:absolute; top:150px; left:150px;opacity: 0}
```

### jQuery

```
var grower = $('.grower');
var flag = 0;

$('.click').click(function() {
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();
    var windowHeight = $(window).height();

    var left = windowWidth / 2 - 150;
    var top = windowHeight / 2 - 150;
    var w = 300;
    var h = 300;

    if (flag == 0) {

        grower.css({
            left: left, top: top, width: w, height: h, opacity: 0
        });
        grower
            .show('scale', {percent: 100}, 500, function(){ flag = 1; })
            .animate({'opacity':'1'} , { duration: 500, queue: false, easing: 'easeInCubic'});;
    }
    else if (flag == 1) {
        grower
            .hide('scale', {percent: 50}, 500, function(){ flag = 0; })
            .animate({'opacity':'0'} , { duration: 500, queue: false});
    }
});
```

Comment: can u plzz explain the below line in detail. grower
            .show('scale', {percent: 100}, 500, function(){ flag = 1; })
            .animate({'opacity':'1'} , { duration: 500, queue: false});;

Comment: i scale then percentage like with show() function... what it does? first u show and then animate. what is the utility of animate here if div is visible using show()? actually how this line works i just do not understand.....plzz explain in detail that how show & animate work together. thanks

Comment: Well actually `.animate` isn't after `.show` but in the same time (notice `queue: false`). Purpose of that is to combine rescaling and fading effect. It is maybe little unclear, but if I was trying use `.effect` instead of `.hide` it acts different.

Comment: thanks for ur answer. i need to have sound knowledge regarding jquery UI animation. need command over this kind of syntax like  .show('scale', {percent: 100}... so please guide me which tutorial i should read to get familiar with above syntax.

Comment: Well all I know is from [jQuery UI docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/show/), [jQuery .animate](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) and also here, I mean Stack Overflow.

Comment: one question regarding the usage of scale animation. here u use scale like show('scale', {percent: 100} . so i just need to know that always we have to give value for scale i percentage or we can give also value like 200px. can't we give the value in pixel? plzz answer. thanks

Comment: For values in pixels use `size` instead of `scale` and `{ to: { width: 200, height: 60 } }` for effect options.

Comment: i am not sure whether u have seen or not that the example code u provided. there is some glitch that when div appear with growing effect then opacity is not working. just go to ur fiddler url and just check. when div is appearing then it should appear like that div should fade in gradually but now it is just growing. when div is shrinking then the effect is perfect because div is shrinking with fade out effect gradually. i hope i am clear what i am trying to say. so would u plzz work again on ur code as a result when div is appearing then it should grow with fade in effect.

Comment: can u plzz convert this line with size. .show('scale', {percent: 100}, 500, function(){ flag = 1; })

Comment: Well opacity effect on showing seems to for bit different than same effect on hiding, but that effect is working. I add additional easing option, is it looking better now? http://jsfiddle.net/Sj4eG/34/

Comment: this line will work? show('size', 300px, 500, function(){ flag = 1; }) if i use size instead of scale ?

Answer (score 2):

You set left and right wrong. `$('#grower').width()` is a current width (when you start animation), not target one. You should set `left` to `left:(windowWidth/2 - w/4)`, because it'll have target width equals to `w/2`. Then `w/2` is left for left and right margins, so `(windowWidth/2 - w/4)` is the middle. Same story with `top`.

Working sample: http://jsfiddle.net/lolo/Sj4eG/21/

Comment: ur sample work but if click on click here button then u can see it is not being center from the second click. so please have a look and do the changes to make it appear center always.